# Is there any point levelling all the heroines?

Tags: conception-2

I'm finding Conception 2 kind of grindy - and this is partially due to me trying to keep all the heroines at around the same level.

Is there any reason to continue this in order to finish the main game? or if I'm decided on a certain character's route?

Should I focus on a single character in order to finish the game faster, or will it bite me later on?